# Difficulty trying to get number of rows for a UITableView with multiple sections

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, nsarray

My app is crashing and it's caused by my number of rows in section method. It looks ok to me though.

I'm looping using the amount of sections I have and with each iteration I'm getting the number of rows for that specific section and setting the value of a var returned at the end of the method to the Int that represents the number of rows. How ever the app crashes.

**Title for header in sections:**

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return _sections[section]
    }
```

**Number of sections in table view:**

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    for location in objects {

        var resortName = location["resort"] as NSString

        if !contains(_sections, resortName) {
            _sections.append(resortName)
        }

    }

    return _sections.count
}
```

**Number of rows in section method:**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    var rowsInSection = 0 as Int

    for var i = 0; i < tableView.numberOfSections(); i++ {

        rowsInSection += tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(i)
    }

    return rowsInSection
}
```

objects is an NSArray of PFObjects.

Comment: The numberOfRowsInSection method is supposed to return the number of rows in each section, not the total number of rows in all sections.

Comment: @rdelmar I edited my question description to make more sense. I'm returning the number of rows for a section not the total rows for all sections.

Comment: No you're not. You're looping over every section and adding the number of rows in each section before you return rowsInSection. That should give you the total number of rows in the data source. If I understand your data source correctly, you should be returning [_sections[section] count]. No need for any loops.

Comment: @rdelmar That isn't working for me. _sections is an array of strings e.g. "resort 1", "resort 2", "resort 3", resort 4", "resort 4", "resort 1". So resort 4 showing up twice would be 2 rows in that section because each string in that array is a section. If two identical strings come up it just means more than one activity is based at that resort.

Comment: The problem is the `for` loop in `numberOfRowsInSection` - you're recursively calling the method and iterating/adding up ALL rows in every section from 0 -> the total # of sections. That means every section thinks it contains ALL rows instead of just its own. The point of the method is to return the # of rows for only 1 specific section. If you can't get an accurate count of rows this way due to repeated resort names, it sounds like your data structure needs tweaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to you question depends on what exactly you are trying to display in the table.  The code you have written doesn't make sense.  It looks like, you are trying to display a list of resorts, right?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

This method will be called to determine the number of rows in the specified `section`.  It's not asking for the grand total of all the rows across all sections.  You'll need to calculate the number of rows needed per section, and return that.

Comment: Sorry edited my question description. What I want is to return the number of rows in a section. I have resorts and activities and some activities share the same the same resort. So these activities are grouped together in a section. Each section represents a resort.